# Freak "1" number appear after require and echo blanc file

Tags: php, echo, require, sign

I have very freak problem :-)

Please, see this simple website:
http://tests.vipserv.org/

There is... "1" number. But in code there is no any "1"...

I converted eol to Unix. No results. Also changed coding to UTF with/without boom.

"Website" is created from files:
index.php:

```
<?php
class View {
    public static $TPL_VIEW = 'view.php';

    public static function renderView($template, $data = array()) {
        echo require $template;
    }

    public static function generateView($template, $data = array()) {
        return require $template;
    }
}

View::renderView(View::$TPL_VIEW, '');
?>
```

and view.php:

```
(blanc)
```

You can download files from:

http://ge.tt/4Td1TeI2/v/1

http://ge.tt/4Td1TeI2/v/0

Thanks,
A.

Comment: `require` doesn't return the output of the included file. That is echoed already. Your first function just needs to call `require` without echo. The second one would probably need [*output buffering*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to grab the output and return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are echoing it out yourself. According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a
>   warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file,
>   return 1.

So instead of:

```
echo require $template;
```

You probably want:

```
require $template;
```

Assuming that your template is not supposed to actually return anything of course.

Comment: Hehehe, thanks :-) Very long time without programming. Don't ask how many time I waste.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo require $template;
```

`require` returns if include succeeded or not i.e. true or false or 1 or 0.
so echo is displaying it.

Comment: Hehehe, thanks :-) Very long time without programming. Don't ask how many time I waste.